# Navigation menu overflow in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, html, menu

I am developing a wordpress theme but the navigation menu items overflow the content.

So when I resize it or adds new items in the menu they seems to go out of header scope.

Below I have added the code and a screenshot.

```
  <header class="site-header">
        <h1><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
        <h5><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h5>

        <nav class="site-nav">
          <?php
          $args = $args = array('theme_location' => 'primary', );
          ?>
          <?php wp_nav_menu($args);?>
        </nav>
    </header>


/* Navigation  */

  .site-nav ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.site-nav ul:before, site-nav ul:after{content: ""; display: table;}
.site-nav ul:after {clear: both;}
.site-nav ul{*zoom: 1;}

.site-nav ul li{
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

/* Site header menu */
.site-header nav ul li{
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.site-header nav ul li a:link,
.site-header nav ul li a:visited{
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  border: 1px solid #892ae1;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.site-header nav ul li a:hover{
  background-color: #ECECEC;
}
.site-header nav ul li.current-menu-item a:link,
.site-header nav ul li.current-menu-item a:visited{
  background-color: #006ec3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Below is the screenshot of the it.
[Click to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PZ5J.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of float:left; I think. 
Please try use below code in your CSS;

```
.site-header:after{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Victoria. You are awesome.

Comment: @TakshakRajput No worries. Enjoy coding :)